# Best way to enhance PagedList with UI-specific data and not break MVVM pattern

Tags: android, mvvm, android-mvvm

I'm new to MVVM pattern, but I really liked how PagedList simplifies working with paged data in repository.

But now I have the following situation:

- I have repository with method like this:

  `fun getLibraryItems(): LiveData<PagedList<ItemInfo>>`

Where `ItemInfo` is Repository-specific and doesn't 'know' about UI.

- Next I want to 'enhance' this data object with UI specific data (map to another ui data object), which I can get only from context-aware components, f.e. it's Drawable resource.

But I cannot do 'map' straight forward from `PagedList<X>` to another `PagedList<Y>`, if I want it - I need to update my data source to accept 'mapper' function, like this:

```
fun <T> getLibraryItems(mapper: (ItemInfo) -> T): LiveData<PagedList<T>> {
        return dataSource
            .getLibraryItems()
            .map(mapper)
            .toLiveData()
}
```

This way I can 'map' `ItemInfo` to UI-specific type `T`, but I cannot do it in ViewModel, because loading Drawable resources in ViewModel is (as I understand) anti-pattern.

I don't understand how and where should I call this 'mapper', should it be Activity/Fragment or am I missing smth and over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible that you map the data inside the ViewModel as you've suggested, but instead of loading Drawable resource right there you pass its identifier only. And then in your UI layer (RecyclerView Adapter,Activity or whatever) load the resource by its identifier. This way you won't have to deal with context-specific methods inside ViewModel. Also if you don't wan't to deal with android resource id's (e.g. R.drawable.my_image) you'll have to keep your own ID system and then map it to android resource id inside UI layer, though I personally consider this redundant complication.

---

#### Edit: After re-reading your question I see that my post didn't fully answer it, so here's a bit more on architecture:

Since you want to map a domain object to UI-specific object, you're right that doing so inside a ViewModel isn't the best practice and not a [clean architecture](https://fernandocejas.com/blog/engineering/2014-09-03-architecting-android-the-clean-way/) way. So the right way would be to do such mappings in your UI layer just before you display the object. Since you work with PagedList I can assume your RecyclerView adapter extends PagedListAdapter. Then you can create an abstraction for supporting mappings inside an adapter.

```kotlin
abstract class MyPagedAdapter<T, R, VH: RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
    val dataMapper: (T)->R, 
    diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>
): PagedListAdapter<T, VH>(diffCallback) {
    fun getMappedItem(position: Int) = dataMapper.invoke(getItem(position))
}


class LibraryItemAdapter(
    dataMapper: (LibraryItem)->UILibraryItem,
): MyPagedAdapter<LibraryItem, UILibraryItem, ViewHolderType>(dataMapper, /* provide diff callback here */) {
    /* implement onCreateViewHolder and getItemViewType here */

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolderType, position: Int) {
        val item = getMappedItem(position)
        // configure view holder to display selected item
    }
 
}


// Then inside your fragment/activity:
val mapper: (LibraryItem) -> UILibraryItem = { /* use your context-aware components to create an object for UI */ }
recyclerView.adapter = LibraryItemAdapter(mapper)
```

P.S: I'd also like to highlight that mapping the whole list inside your ViewModel/Repository/elsewhere to another class which holds a Drawable, Bitmap or any other large structure is a bad idea, you could end up flooding memory with Drawables which may be not even displayed at the moment. Get your drawables only when you're going to use them and don't store them in a list. My initial answer and later edit both keep you from doing so

P.P.S.: Don't put too much work into your mapper as it may load the UI thread a lot when user scrolls a large list quickly. Do all your business logic in domain/repository layer.